# ios core data - most of the time got entity problems?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, entity

Whenever I work with Core Data, I can get the program to run and does what it is suppose to do. But i often get issues when trying to save data I get an error like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Feedings''

And for no reason as far as I can tell.

```
-(IBAction)saveData:(id)sender
{

Feedings *newFeed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Feedings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

newFeed.time01 = time01TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time02 = time02TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time03 = time03TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time04 = time04TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time05 = time05TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time06 = time06TxtFld.text;
newFeed.time07 = time07TxtFld.text;

newFeed.feed01 = mls01TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed02 = mls02TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed03 = mls03TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed04 = mls04TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed05 = mls05TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed06 = mls06TxtFld.text;
newFeed.feed07 = mls07TxtFld.text;


[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database

[self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddAppVCWasTapped:self];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Feedings" message:@"A new feeding record has been added." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
 }
```

This is the code I have for adding information to the database and Xcode has no errors - why is it so hard to get the app to work properly??

Image of BreakPoint
[image: Image of BreakPoint]

---

I added this line to ViewDidLoad Method:

```
NSLog(@"Entities : %@",[[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"time01"]);
```

Which Returns this:

> 2012-08-25 13:33:43.572 Feeding[735:fb03] Entities : (null)

Which is properly the reason for the crash

Comment: Is "Feedings" in your data model file? Is it "Feeding" instead?

Comment: The entity is called Feedings - there seems to be no logical reason for the crash

Comment: Are you sure the correct managed object model is loaded at this point? Have you tried cleaning and deleting the app from your device? Are you sure you have the correct model version selected as default? Is there anything else you can say about when this happens?

Comment: I have cleared and reset the simulator several times - there is only one model. I thought it would be loaded when I start the app

Comment: This doesn't make sense

Feedings shall be initialized with Feeding's initialize method. You shall write 'NSEntityDescription *newfeed = [NSEntityDescription....' to make that work. I don't know but what you're writing here doesn't make sense for me

Comment: @JeffKranenburg You should find the code that loads your model and ensure it's doing what you expect. You might also check to see if self.managedObjectContext is nil.

Comment: @TheNavigator The code Jeff shows for his insert looks fine to me; look at the docs for NSEntityDescription.

Comment: @TheNavigator I have updated the code, hope it helps

Comment: ok, I am gonna try and figure out to see what the ManagedObjectControl returns - may take me a while :-)

Comment: Right before the crash, what's the value of `self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel`?

Comment: @Drew - I have added an image before the Save Action - that is all I know how to check that. I found an NSLog, but it is not returning it yet.

Comment: @Drew - I have added the NSLog with it's result

Comment: @JeffKranenburg, I guess you need to share it?....

Comment: Share what? How do I do  that?

Comment: Please print the whole entities dict, as well as the managedObjectModel. It is not expected that "time01" is a valid key for the entities dictionary, so your current print statement output is unhelpful.

Comment: Alright - I think I am gonna need to start from scratch again, because I am seeing from these comments, that I even struggle with these basic things:-) Thanks for you responses:-)